# How to return image files on the phone as LiveData in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I get media files on device with the following function in my ViewModel. I provide it to a ListAdapter for RecyclerView where image thumbnails are listed. User can delete some images from the device while my app is in the background. When my app comes to foreground, I need to update my list accordingly. Is there any way to achieve it with LiveData? Otherwise, I will retrieve image files in `onResume()` and call `submitList()` on the ListAdapter.

```
fun getAllMediaFilesOnDevice(context: Context): List<File> {
    val files: ArrayList<File> = ArrayList()
    try {
        val columns = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME
        )
        val cursor = MergeCursor(
            arrayOf(
                context.getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    columns, null, null, null
                ),
                context.getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    columns, null, null, null
                ),
                context.getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    columns, null, null, null
                ),
                context.getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    columns, null, null, null
                )
            )
        )
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        files.clear()
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {
            var path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA))
            val lastPoint = path.lastIndexOf(".")
            path = path.substring(0, lastPoint) + path.substring(lastPoint).toLowerCase()
            files.add(File(path))
            cursor.moveToNext()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return files
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your recyclerview adapter in a reactive way in the fragment/activity:

```
viewModel.files.observe(this, Observer { files ->
    //update files in adapter
})
```

In the ViewModel add a MutableLiveData to post the latest files to (as a good practice keep it private an only expose the LiveData):

```
private val mutableFiles: MutableLiveData<List<File>> = MutableLiveData()
val files: LiveData<List<File>> get() = mutableFiles
```

Then adjust the files method to post files to the LiveData instead of returning it:

```
fun getAllMediaFilesOnDevice(context: Context):  {
    //get the files like before...
    //then post it to the mutable livedata to notify observers
    mutableFiles.postValue(files)
}
```

Comment: I still have to call `getAllMediaFilesOnDevice()` from the fragment's `onResume()`, am I right? The image list is not updated when my app comes to foreground after I took some shots.

Comment: I want not to make any call in `onResume()` myself, but I want LiveData to update file list automatically if there is any change on the device.

Comment: This is what i am dealing with also. No solutions up to now. Do you have any updates on the question?